# In Eclipse, How do I print a value stored in shared preferences next to a string specified in string resources?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want the following to appear on the screen:

String(from string resources): value(from shared preferences)

String(from string resources): value(from shared preferences)

etc.

my .java file (edited after comments):

```
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ActivityResults5 extends Activity {

    Button button, submitButton;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String oResult = getResources().getString(R.string.resultsO) + sharedPreferences.getString("facet1", "Default");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout activityResults5= new LinearLayout(this);
        TextView tvO=new TextView(this);
        Button b=new Button(this);

        LayoutParams dimensions= new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        activityResults5.setLayoutParams(dimensions);

        LayoutParams viewDimensions= new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tvO.setLayoutParams(viewDimensions);
        b.setLayoutParams(viewDimensions);


        activityResults5.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        tvO.setText(oResult);
        b.setText("Button here");

        activityResults5.addView(tvO);
        activityResults5.addView(b);

        setContentView(activityResults5);
        addListenerOnButton();


    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;
        submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);

        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityResults12.class);
            startActivity(intent);

             }

    });

}
}
```

Comment: where you are saving values in `shared preferences` ?

Comment: you can simply concat two strings : `String newText = getResources().getString(R.string.submit) + sharedPref.getString(key_value);`

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K: I'm saving in an XML file called "MyData". I'm not showing the screens where I ask for user input and that input is saved to shared preferences.

Comment: @ SweetWisher シ: I may have confused you with my submit button. As any answer to my question would not include it. The button is only used to take the user to the next activity screen. That is, I want the concatenated strings to appear on the screen when the user gets to this screen (no button clicks necessary).

Comment: U can put this code in `onCreate`

Comment: I added the concat string to a text view in the class file (in onCreate), but my app crashes when I get to this screen. What am I doing wrong? I have edited my original post to reflect how I've interpreted your comments.

Comment: This video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBYez0_8AOI&index=41&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6hYgvtkaWvwAVvOFB7fkLa and the comments above, combined, answer my question.

Comment: My app is still crashing when it gets to this screen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the proper way to print a string stored in shared preferences next to a string from resources:

```
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ActivityResults5 extends Activity {

    Button button, submitButton;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String oResult = getResources().getString(R.string.resultsO) + sharedPreferences.getString("facet1", "Default");

        LinearLayout activityResults5= new LinearLayout(this);
        TextView tvO=new TextView(this);
        Button b=new Button(this);

        LayoutParams dimensions= new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        activityResults5.setLayoutParams(dimensions);

        LayoutParams viewDimensions= new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tvO.setLayoutParams(viewDimensions);
        b.setLayoutParams(viewDimensions);


        activityResults5.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        tvO.setText(oResult);
        b.setText("Button here");

        activityResults5.addView(tvO);
        activityResults5.addView(b);

        setContentView(activityResults5);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
submitButton .setText(getResources().getString(R.string.submit+<Your shared preference value>));
```

Comment: I may have confused you with my submit button. As any answer to my question would not include it. The button is only used to take the user to the next activity screen. That is, I want the concatenated strings to appear on the screen when the user gets to this screen (no button clicks necessary on this screen).

Comment: getResources().getString(R.string.submit+<Your shared preference value>) will give you the string, now use it in whatever way you want to use